# Getting wrong string grid from CSV file

Tags: c#, .net, csv

This is my code which I use to get string grid from CSV file using CsvFileReader class on [this URL](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/415732/Reading-and-Writing-CSV-Files-in-Csharp#_comments)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  // Read sample data from CSV file
  ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
  List<string> U = new List<string>();
  U.Clear();
  list.Clear();
  using (CsvFileReader reader = new CsvFileReader(@"C:\\path_to_file\file.csv"))
  {
    CsvRow row = new CsvRow();
    while (reader.ReadRow(row))
    {
      U.Clear();
      foreach (string s in row)
      {
        //Console.Write(s);
        //Console.Write(" ");
        U.Add(s);
      }
      list.Add(U);
      //Console.WriteLine();
    }
  }

  Console.WriteLine(list);
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

However I am not getting the string grid as I want. The 'list' contains only duplicated copies of the last csv row which is equal to the number of rows in CSV file and not the exact grid I am looking for.

Comment: See if there is commas in the data, you should use escaping mechanism of CSV files

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what you mean by string "grid", but I guess that you mean a `List` that will contain `List<string>`'s for each row of the CSV file.

Your basic error is using the same list (`U`) for the inner loop over and over again. [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) is a reference type in C# so you end up adding the exact same object again and again and again.

I haven't tested the code, but something along these lines should work.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  // Read sample data from CSV file
  List<List<string>> list = new List<List<string>>();
  using (CsvFileReader reader = new CsvFileReader(@"C:\\path_to_file\file.csv"))
  {
    CsvRow row = new CsvRow();
    while (reader.ReadRow(row))
    {
      List<string> rowList = new List<string>();
      foreach (string s in row)
      {
        //Console.Write(s);
        //Console.Write(" ");
        rowList.Add(s);
      }
      list.Add(rowList);
      //Console.WriteLine();
    }
  }

  foreach (List<string> rowList in list)
  {
     foreach (string cellData in rowList)
     {
        Console.Write(cellData + "\t");
     }
     Console.WriteLine();
  }
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Thanks... this was what i was looking for....had used the wrong concept even for another project ....so will try rectifying it..

Comment: As a rule of thumb, it's clearest if you declare and instantiate the variables as near as possible to the place where they are used.

Answer (score 0):

I can provide you a function to read tabulator separated csv into datatable:
Save excel to tab separated csv, and you can read it.

```
    public static DataTable ParseCSV(string path)
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(path, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] items = line.Split('\t');
                items[1] = ToUpperFirstLetter(items[1].ToLower());
                if (dt.Columns.Count == 0)
                {
                    // column names
                    foreach (string t in items)
                        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(t.Trim(), typeof(string)));
                }
                else
                {
                    //data
                    dt.Rows.Add(items);
                }
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

usage:

```
    var dt = ParseCSV("c:\\data\\some.txt")
```